# Is it possible to use software RAID inside a Docker container?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, mdadm, ubuntu-20.04

Before anyone asks why you'd want to do that, I'm using [molecule](https://molecule.readthedocs.io) to test my "infrastructure as code" locally before deploying it to actual machines.

Start by creating two block devices:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test0 bs=1M count=10
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test1 bs=1M count=10
# losetup /dev/loop0 /tmp/test0
# losetup /dev/loop1 /tmp/test1
```

Now create the array:

```
# mdadm --create /dev/md127 --metadata=0.90 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.19.76-linuxkit/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module md_mod not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.76-linuxkit
mdadm: Fail create md127 when using /sys/module/md_mod/parameters/new_array
mdadm: unexpected failure opening /dev/md127
```

I tried installing the `linux-generic` package to populate the missing `/lib/modules` directory, but it doesn't look like the correct version of that package exists for the running kernel (this is on Ubuntu 20.04):

```
# uname -r
4.19.76-linuxkit

# apt show linux-generic | grep Version
Version: 5.4.0.12.15
```

Comment: Did you consider using the molecule vagrant driver for this rather than the default docker driver ? Vagrant driver will let you spin up VMs where ti will be much easier to acheive what you want in this case. I don't think you can realiably test such things with docker container (if you can test at all....).